# Show all nodes except two with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to show all nodes and their values except two of them. For example, show all except 'type' and 'price'

```
<xsl:for-each select="market/device">
<!-- ... --> 
  <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()!='type']"> <!-- <<< here --> 
    <li><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></li>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
  </xsl:for-each>
<!-- ... -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What do you want us to do? Please see the How to Ask section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: You do know about the `not` function(!) in XPath, yes?

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide an input, I just set up the following XML as an example:

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markets>
   <market>
     <device>
        <type>type value</type>
        <price>price value</price>
        <nottype>nottype value</nottype>
        <notprice>notprice value</notprice> 
        <else>else value</else>
    </device>
   </market> 
 </markets>
```

When following XSLT is applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <head>

    </head>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="markets">
<ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="market/device">
   <xsl:for-each select="*[not((local-name() = 'type') or (local-name() = 'price'))]">
     <li><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></li>
     <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each> 
</ul>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

following output is produced (ony relevant part posted):

```
<ul>
  <li>nottype</li>
  <li>nottype value</li>
  <li>notprice</li>
  <li>notprice value</li>
  <li>else</li>
  <li>else value</li>
</ul>
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not